# Getting Users current Page url in djangorestframework

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

How can I get the url a user is making their request **"from"** in Django Rest Framework?

Currently using
`const current_url = window.location.href const api_key = "API_KEY"`

`` fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/api/${api_key}?url=${current_url}) ``

But I feel this method isn't secure enough as it can be altered from the front end, and a different URL can be hardcoded there.

So, I need to get the user's current url from the Backend.

Comment: `request.build_absolute_uri()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: No...
This is returning the API end point
If the user's current url is "localhost:8000" and they're making the GET request to the API end point...

I want to return that localhost:8000 and not the api url

Comment: Well; then your solution is as close as anything else is to being secure. Another option would've been to check the HTTP-referrer server side; but that again, can be forged. Why do you need this functionality if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I'm working on a Content Management System. Users will have to define their Site Urls, in which their Contents will be rendered once they fetch the API passing the current url as a parameter. But I just want to make this dynamic because anybody can actually hardcore another person's url to his/her own site and it'll still work. I hope you understand...